# Is there a 'kramdownify' filter in jekyll?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, kramdown

In jekyll there's a `markdownify` liquid filter which will parse the text to html according to standard markdown specifications. However I want to filter the text to the kramdown specifications so I can use kramdown [features](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html) (such as classname, inline style etc..).

The default `markdownify` filter doesn't parse kramdown, I have tried using `kramdownify`, and I have already set the default markdown parser to kramdown in `_config.yml`. Both to no avail.

Here's an example I want to achieve:

`some-blog.md`

```
---
layout: default
page_description: >
   **kramdown formated text**
   {: style="color: red"} // kramdown specification for inline style

---
```

`default.html`

```
{{ page.page_description | markdownify }}
```

**Expected Output**:

[image]

**Actual Output**:

[image]

**Summary**

kramdown does work in my blog post content. But it doesn't work anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing `markdownify` filter uses the same converter as the rest of your site.
**The error however is in your front matter.**

```
page_description: >
   **kramdown formated text**
   {: style="color: red"}
```

translates into `'**kramdown formated text** {: style="color: red"}'`

You need to use the *pipe character* (`|`) to let YAML respect newlines. So simply edit your front matter as following and you should get the expected output:

```
page_description: |
   **kramdown formated text**
   {: style="color: red"}
```